# When do we need to attach source to a jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, build, continuous-integration

When do we need to attach source to a jar?

Can we debug without attaching the source code?
Can we see the stacktrace line numbers without the source (AFIAK we can't)?

What is the best practice for local builds? Do we need the source code?
What about CI?
Can we leave the source code only for production release?

Thanks,
   Omer

Comment: In which environment? Deploying artifacts to Maven Central? Or in a company environment ?

Comment: Company environment

Comment: I would suggest to create source jar's in your environment and deploy them to your repository manager...this is very convenient for devs which is supported by all IDE's out there...At least for release builds...for the CI builds it depends..if there are many other projects which consume your artifacts as for example SNAPSHOT deps ?

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to also publish the `sources` jar along with your `binary` jar in your internal (or external) Maven repository. It makes life of the developer that is working with your code much easier since they can see your comments / browse the codebase and be able to have all that at debug time. Now as you are saying even if the `sources` jar is not published, developers have ways around it primarily relying on their IDE. In **Eclipse** for instance you can install the [Java Decompile plugin](http://jd.benow.ca/) that would give you access to the code during debug time or on **IntelliJ** there is something similar without the need of installing a plugin.